# Unity built game not starting

Tags: unity-game-engine

After installing the localization package in the game and performing the build, when the .exe game file is opened, the game is not launching (only the windows task bar shows not responding). I also have the previous builds for the same game and they are launching without problems. The problem arises with the current build after installing the locatlization package.

While building the game, Unity did not show any kind of error!

Here is the screenshot for reference!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar issue but not for localization package. In my case, version of package and version of Unity didnt match thats why I got that error so I turned back my Unity version as same as the package itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a version difference issue. I changed the localization package version to its recommended version and it worked. At least, a developer expects a comprehensive error from the unity system which was not the case.

Comment: You're welcome. I totally agree what you said, unfortunately often extensive cases are caused by simple things that the developers didn't think possible.